# Full Simplify giving zero answer?

Tags: equation-solving

```
sol = Solve[{
   -I*Ω1*σab - I*Ω2*σac + I*Ω1*σba + I*Ω2*σca == 0, 
   I*Ω1*σab - I*Ω1*σba - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σbc + I*E^(-I*Δk* z)*Ωμ*σcb == 0, 
   σaa + σbb + σcc == 1, 
   - Γab*σab - I*Ω1*σaa + I*Ω1*σbb - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σac + I*Ω2*σcb == 0,
   -Γac*σac - I*Ω2*σaa + I*Ω2*σcc - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σab + I*Ω1*σbc == 0, 
   -Γcb*σcb + I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σbb - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σcc + 
     I*Ω2*σab - I*Ω1*σca == 0, 
   -Γab*σba + I*Ω1* σaa - I*Ω1*σbb - I*Ω2*σbc + 
     I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σca == 0, 
   -Γca*σca + I*Ω2*σaa - I*Ω2*σcc + I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σba - 
     I*Ω1*σcb == 0, 
   -Γcb*σbc - I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σbb + I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σcc - 
     I*Ω2*σba + I*Ω1*σac == 0}, 
  {σaa, σbb, σcc, σab, σba, σac, σca, σbc, σcb}]
```

After solving these linear equations, I want to `FullSimlify` the expression solution of `σab`.

But it is giving zero. Is there anything wrong with the equations? Or am I doing the programme wrongly?

```
σab1 = FullSimplify[σab /. sol]
```

> 0.

Comment: I too get `0` as the final answer.  Do you have reason to believe that this result is incorrect?  By the way, Use `Simplify` instead of `FullSimplify` to reduce run time.

Answer (score 1):

With `sol` as computed in the question,

```
Simplify[sol] // Flatten

(* {σaa -> 1/3, σbb -> 1/3, σcc -> 1/3, σab -> 0, σba -> 0, σac -> 0, 
    σca -> 0, σbc -> 0, σcb -> 0} *)
```

This answer is valid, as can be seen by designating the set of nine equations to be `Solve`d in the question as `eqs` and computing

```
eqs /. %

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Thus, `Simplify[σab /. sol]` is indeed `0`.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey.  I have to check my equations.